# error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type for custom interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an interface for an array of objects

```
export interface UpdateMediaList {
    [index: number]: ContactResponse;
}

interface ContactResponse {
    contactId: number;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    imgDisplayPath: string;
    inMediaList: true;
    jobTitle: string;
    lastName: string;
    mediaOutletId: number;
    mediaOutletName: string;
    openRate: string;
    phone: string;
    responseRate: string;
    secureRate: string;
}
```

and then I use it in my service ...

```
postUpdateMediaList(param, body, url = this.urls.mediaList.updateMediaList) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('sortType', param.sortType);
    params = params.set('numRows', param.numRows);
    params = params.set('startRow', param.startRow);
    return this.http.post<UpdateMediaList>(url, body, {params: params});
}
```

and now I am getting this error

```
ERROR in src/app/modules/media-list/containers/media-list-builder/media-list-builder.component.ts(142,22): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'UpdateMediaList'
```

Which is in this block of code:

```
this.mediaList = response
    .filter(items => items.inMediaList === true)
    .map(items => items.contactId);
while (this._contacts.value.length !== 0) {
    this._contacts.removeAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Just use `type UpdateMediaList  = ContactResponse[]`?

Comment: @jcalz "Just use type UpdateMediaList = ContactResponse[]?" where?

Comment: instead of your current definition of `UpdateMediaList`, which is only saying "this thing has numeric-keyed properties with `ContactResponse` values" and not "this is an array of `ContactResponse` values".  An actual array has all those array methods like `filter()`.  The numeric-indexed object might not.

Comment: That is, all arrays have numeric-indexed properties, but not all objects with numeric-indexed properties are arrays.

Comment: Have you checked which type the response is? i doubt it is of type array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition:

```
export interface UpdateMediaList {
    [index: number]: ContactResponse;
}
```

does not define a TypeScript [`Array`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1117-L1267), but just an object with numeric keys whose values are `ConstactResponse` objects.  An `Array<T>` does have [numeric-keyed properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1266), but it also has all the `Array` methods like [`filter()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1227-L1238), which you are apparently relying on.

Here is something that meets your `UpdateMediaList` definition:

```
declare const someContactResponse: ContactResponse;
const weirdUpdateMediaList: UpdateMediaList = {0: someContactResponse};
```

As you can see, `weirdUpdateMediaList` has a numeric-key property but is not an array.  You wouldn't want to allow this code:

```
weirdUpdateMediaList.filter(x => true); // error at compile time
```

because it would blow up at runtime with `weirdUpdateMediaList.filter is not a function`.

---

Assuming you are actually getting an `Array` from your back end, then you should just use `Array` like this instead of your definition of `UpdateMediaList`:

```
export type UpdateMediaList = Array<ContactResponse>;
```

or, equivalently

```
export type UpdateMediaList = ContactResponse[];
```

Then, if you tried this you'd get an error:

```
const weirdUpdateMediaList: UpdateMediaList = {0: someContactResponse}; 
// error!  not assignable to type 'ContactResponse[]'.
//   Property 'length' is missing in type '{ 0: ContactResponse; }'.
```

And it would be safe to assume that any object of type `UpdateMediaList` is an actual `Array` with all the methods you need.

Does that make sense?  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. This does make sense now.