# Create Radio Button Alert from Firestore Data

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a radio button alert by using the data in fireStore. I generated an observable by valueChanges() but console.log returns Undefined when I used it in the function that can't read the data and eventually cannot insert the values for radio button. I am new to fireStore and ionic.

I have also tried using .get().then(function(doc) but returns error as not a function. I have also tried using subscribe() but also not able to give me the actual data, or I have missed something. I have google for many days but just can't find the solution. I hope somebody could help.

```
myMemberList = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
       public alertCtrl: AlertController,
       public firestore: AngularFirestore, 
       public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    ) { }

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
     if (user) {
      this.userId = user.uid;
      this.fireStoreTaskList = this.firestore.doc<any>('users/' + 
      this.userId).collection('Member').valueChanges();
     }
  });
}

// create the inputs for radio button //
createInputs() {
    const theNewInputs = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < this.fireStoreTaskList.length; i++) { // undefined
    theNewInputs.push(
      {
        type: 'radio',
        label: this.fireStoreTaskList.memberName,     // undefined
        value: this.fireStoreTaskList.memberId,       // undefined
        checked: false      
      }
    );

  } {
  console.log(theNewInputs);
  }
  return theNewBeneInputs;
}

// Radio button alert to choose data //
async selectMember() {
  this.myMemberList = this.createInputs();
  const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
    header: 'Member',
    inputs: this.myMemberList,

    buttons: [{ text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel' },
              { text: 'OK',
                 handler: data => {
                 console.log(data)
                }
              }
              ]
  });
  await alert.present();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with Ionic 4 for some time now and I have also integrated Firebase Firestore in my app. I didn't really understand the whole description, but I have a solution for you initial question **"I want to create a radio button alert by using the data in Firestore"**

I assume that you have already setup your application with your Firebase app, if not then I suggest following the [How to Build An Ionic 4 App with Firebase and AngularFire 5](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-firebase-angularfire-2/).

My example has 1 button, that whenever you click it, it will do the following:

1. Access the Firestore database.
2. Download the Firestore documents.
3. Get the field **memberName** of each document.
4. Add those names in an array of names
5. Create an Alert of Radio Buttons.
6. For the radio buttons it will create a list of radio buttons that will have the names of the members.
7. Display the array.

For my code to work, this is the Firestore database structure that I have followed:

```
.
└── collection: "users"
    └── document: "autogenerated_id"
    |   ├── memberID: "user_id"
    |   └── memberName: "Name 01"
    └── document: "autogenerated_id"
        ├── memberID: "user_id"
        └── memberName: "Name 02"
```

When clicking the button you will see an alert with radio buttons e.g. **Name 01** and **Name 02**

As I have mentioned above, [this is my example code](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/tree/master/Ionic4/Firestore/create_a_radio_button_alert_by_using_the_data_in_firestore). It **loads data from Firestore** and **Creates an alert with radio buttons using that data**, as you have described in your question. I have added a lot of comments for you in the code. If this is not exactly what you were looking for, take a look at the code and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Excellent. It works!. This is exactly what I am looking for. The example code is very good and the footnote is very detailed. Thanks a million :)

Comment: I am glad that this resolved your issue. Please mark the answer as solution to give the question more visibility, as it might also help other members of the community!

Comment: Hi Andrei, is there any way I can capture the values of both memberID and memberName (maybe some more values) at the same time, so that I can deploy later in the data handler?

Comment: Hey there! You will have to use an [array element of interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469244/how-can-i-define-an-interface-for-an-array-of-objects-with-typescript). e.g. Add `interface Data {
  memberID?: string;
  memberName?: string;
}` then add `data: Data[] = [];` within the main class and then you can `this.data.push( { memberID: doc.data().memberID, memberName: doc.data().memberName});` in the part where you are loading the data. Hope it helps!

Comment: @ Andrei Cusnir  I am not familiar with the usage of interface. Based on your comments, I have made changes to your example code as below but can't get the values of memberID and memberName in the console.log. Did I put the codes in the wrong place? Can you help to correct it? Thanks.

Comment: You did some minor mistakes in the code. I have fixed your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58188997/4037220), however as this might me a question for other members of the community, I believe that further interactions must be done in a new Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATED CODE FOR LOADING memberID and memberName into the array of type interface.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    //Import AngularFirestore to access Firestore database
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    //Import AlertControll to display alerts
    import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';


    //You have to add the interface, before the calss' declaration
    interface Data { 
      memberID?: string; 
      memberName?: string; 
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    
      //List that will be used to load the data from Firestore into it
      //members = []; //You don't this anymore
      //Just the array of type interface that you created.
      data: Data[] = [];
    
      //Constractor: add AngularFirestore and AlertController
      constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, public alertController: AlertController) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      //Load data and create the alert

      showAlert(){
    
        //Clear the array before loading again
        this.members = [];
    
        //Access the Collection "users" in Firestore and load all the documents
        this.db.collection("users").ref
        .get()
        .then(async (querySnapshot) => {
    
          //Parse through all the loaded documents
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            //Add the loaded name to the list
            //this.members.push(doc.data().memberName) // You don't need this anymore as you are going to push the loaded data in the new array
            //Pushing the data in the new array or logging it if you want
            this.data.push( { 
              memberID: doc.data().memberID,      //This is how you get the memberID from Firestore document
              memberName: doc.data().memberName}  //This is how you get the memberName from Firestore document
              );
          });
    
          //Create an array of Radio Buttons to be used in the alert
          var newInputs = [];
          
          //Parse through all memebers in the loaded array from Firestore
          for (const d of this.data){
            newInputs.push({
              name: 'radio1', //You can costumize those as well to cast the clicked once afterwards
              type: 'radio',
              label: "ID: " + d.memberID + " name: " + d.memberName, //Add the member and the ID as label
              value: 'value1',
              checked: false
            })
          }
      
          //Create an alert
          const alert = await this.alertController.create({
            header: 'Radio',
            inputs: newInputs, //Add the dynamically  generated array of radio buttons.
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'secondary',
                handler: () => {
                  console.log('Confirm Cancel');
                }
              }, {
                text: 'Ok',
                handler: () => {
                  console.log('Confirm Ok');
                }
              }
            ]
          });
      
          //Present the alert
          await alert.present();
    
    
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
    
      }
```