# How to tell typescript to accept an empty array or a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
const subscriptions: { [key: string]: [() => void]  } = {}

interface ISubscription {
  eventName: string
  callback: () => void
}

export function unsubscribe({ eventName, callback }: ISubscription) {
  if (!subscriptions[eventName]) { return }
  const index = subscriptions[eventName].findIndex((l) => l === callback)
  if (index < 0) { return }
  subscriptions[eventName].splice(index, 1)
}

export function subscribe({ eventName, callback }: ISubscription) {
  if (!subscriptions[eventName]) {
    subscriptions[eventName] = []
  }
  subscriptions[eventName].push(callback)
  return () => unsubscribe({ eventName, callback })
}
```

The issue typescript reports is:

> TS2741: Property '0' is missing in type '[]' but required in type '[() => void]'.

Which comes from trying to assign an empty array to the `subscriptions`:

```js
if (!subscriptions[eventName]) {
  subscriptions[eventName] = []
}
```

This can be fixed by defining the interface to accept an empty array but then there's an issue when assigning a callback:

```js
const subscriptions: { [key: string]: [() => void] | [] } = {}
```

> TS2345: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

A workaround would be:

```js
const subscriptions: { [key: string]: [() => void] } = {}

if (!subscriptions[eventName]) {
  subscriptions[eventName] = [callback]
}
else {
  subscriptions[eventName].push(callback)
}
```

What is the correct way to be able to set it to an empty array and then assign the callback? I tried using the question mark too but I can't seem to get it right. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469244/how-can-i-define-an-interface-for-an-array-of-objects-with-typescript) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misconception. `[() => void]` is a tuple of one element, and that element needs to satisfy the type `() => void`. If you want an array, let it be empty or not, with one or multiple elements, the correct type is `(() => void)[]`.

The following expressions are accepted by `(() => void)[]`:

1. `[]`
2. `[() => { doSomething(); }]`
3. `[() => { doSomething(); }, () => { doSomethingElse(); }]`

While only the expression number 2 is accepted by `[() => void]`.

If you want either an empty array or a tuple of one element, you can just do `[] | [() => void]`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define it as an "array of type":

```
type Subscriptions = {
  [key: string]: Array<()=>void>
}
```

then:

```
const subscriptions: Subscriptions = {}
if (!subscriptions[eventName]) {
  subscriptions[eventName] = []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Pretty straight-forward solution

```
type TCallBackArray = (() => void)[];
interface ISubscriptions { 
    [key: string]: TCallBackArray
};

const subscriptions: ISubscriptions = {}
```

Where `TCallBackArray` is defined as an `array of functions`, and `ISubscriptions` is defined as an [indexer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).