# How to declare mapped property name in React Typescript App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-props

I am trying to figure out why my code is telling me that my mapped data that has a property of 'name' is of type never. I am already declaring the commentsData in the interface but there is obviously an error occuring there.

Please see my code below:

```
interface IProps {
  commentsData: [] 
}

const CommentList: React.FC<IProps> = ({ commentsData }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {commentsData.map(comment => {
        return (
          <div>
            {comment.name}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async ()=> {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => data);
    return {
      props: {
        commentsData: data
      }
    }
}

export default CommentList;
```

And here is the image with the error that Typescript is throwing:
[image]

Anyone here ever saw this error? And how did you solve it. Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Well you didn't specify what `commentsData` is an array **of**. Looks like it's an array of object, so you need to tell Typescript what those objects look like in your interface, e.g. `commentsData: { name: string }[]`

Comment: @Jayce444 sorry, I should've specified how the object looks. I have updated my post to show it

Comment: Ok well check gr33nTHumB's answer below, you have to tell Typescript how the object will look when you're defining it in the interface; then when you map over it in the component, it will know the properties the object has. Will fix your typing issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what the array is of. Something like:

```
interface IComment {
  postId: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  body: string;
}

interface IProps {
  commentsData: IComment[] 
}
```

This way, TypeScript knows what kind of object to expect inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to define an interface with an indexer. because it's look like an array of objects.

I am sharing the link which can help you. [How can i define an interface for array of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469244/how-can-i-define-an-interface-for-an-array-of-objects)